# Telegram bot doesn't respond to message in group rather replies for the same in personal chat

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

Telegram bot using node js doesn't reply in the group. When I text it in the group, it replies to me immediately in my personal chat.
-The group is a supergroup
-The bot is an admin
-Privacy setting is disabled
Yet there is this problem. How do I do it??

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = 'my bot_token here';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
var Hi = "hi";
if (msg.text.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(Hi) === 0) {
    bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, "Hello  " + msg.from.first_name);
} });
```

Comment: Do you have any code snippets? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have been simply trying to make my bot welcome new members..also respond to any greetings like say hi or hello..Since my bot isn't reponding in group at all..so i am unable to check my welcoming part of the code..but the reply to a hi or hello works but it responds privately n not in the group itself even if i /start it and say hi in group..ill add the code snippet below..

Comment: updated the question with code snippet..please check out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use chat.id instead of user.id:

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = 'my bot_token here';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
var Hi = "hi";
if (msg.text.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(Hi) === 0) {
    bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Hello  " + msg.from.first_name);
} });
```

Comment: Another note is that the bot MUST be and admin on that group